# How to create new field in output by annotate() with default value?

Tags: python, django

In SQL it would be:

```sql
SELECT *, 0 as new_field FROM table;
```

I thought in Django it would be like

```py
Article.objects.annotate(new_field=0)
```

but it doesn't work; I get the error:

```py
TypeError: QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): 0.
```

Is there the way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

another solution you can try [value-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import Value, IntegerField

Article.objects.annotate(new_field=Value(0, output_field=IntegerField()))
```

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is make use of [Coalesce](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce).

```py
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

Article.objects.annotate(annotated=Coalesce(Count("field"), 0))
```

Comment: and looks like https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#value-expressions will more simple solution

Answer (score 1):

If you want the exact same behaviour of this SQL statement: `SELECT 0 as new_field ...`

You can use:

```
Article.objects.extra({'new_field': 0})
```

Comment: I didn't know about extra() but for my purpose it still doesn't work, thanks anyway