# Get n value with n parameter with Django Queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

this is my first question. If my question is not clear, let me know :)

So I learn Django (learning by doing) for 4 Months in my project. I have one table name material, which is the table contains material name and price. Here I will describe my table:

| id | materialName | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Not Required | 0 |
| 2 | Material 1 | 123 |
| 3 | Material 2 | 456 |
| 4 | Material 3 | 900 |

I want to calculate the total material price by getting the price from the table. It looks ok if I only want to get 1 price only. But, I need to get 4 values of prices from what the user wants in input. Let's say the user chooses Material 3, Material 2, Not Required and Not Required. So there is 4 material price. Then, I use a queryset like this:

`x = rawmaterial.objects.filter(Q(materialName = 'Material 3') | Q(materialName = 'Material 2') | Q(materialName = 'Not Required') | Q(materialName = 'Not Required')).values_list('price',flat=True)`

but the result is **(900, 456, 0)** not like **(900, 456, 0, 0)**. I have been trying with SQL query using OR, is there any possibility to get 4 values? Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't query like that. Filter will filter out the values, not make them **0**. Instead, you can use [Conditional Expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/). In your case, you can consider [Case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case):

```
from django.db.models import Case, Value, When, F

rawmaterial.objects.annotate(
     required_prices=Case(
         When(materialName__in =['Material 3','Material 2', 'Not Required'], then=F('price')),
         default=Value(0),
     )
).values_list('required_prices', flat=True)
```

FYI, please follow the pep-8 style guide for naming class name (Pascal Case) and field/function names (snake case).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. When I try to run that it shows an error command that mentions I should set the output_field. Is it true if I set like output_field=DecimalField() after default=Value(0) or after F('price')?

Comment: I found the answer about set the output_field. I need to do it from django.db.models import DecimalField. Then i put the output_field=DecimalField() after default=Value(0). I will fix the naming class by follow the pep-8 style. Thanks for the answer, have a nice day :) *reference from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303218/how-to-create-new-field-in-output-by-annotate-with-default-value